# How to retrive the banner image and title for a whatsapp , telegram and wechat group from its group link?

Tags: java, php, telegram, whatsapp, wechat

I am developing a whatsapp + telegram +wechat group listing app

In existing online group listing web sites , like http://groupsor.net , http://wpgroups.net .....

When I enter whatsapp group link in add new group form ,they automatically showing the group banner image and title

[image: banner auto retrived]

I want to implement this in my app

Is there any API for this ?

Please suggest me a solution for all chat apps ?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the **group id** then you can parse/extract group name and image/icon from the Html content of the group link:

Group linK:

```
https://chat.whatsapp.com/<group_ID>
```

example: https://chat.whatsapp.com/Dv2u7cKtGu1Lcg0onb57NV

You can also go thorough these whatsapp API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/groups#retrieve

Comment: I successfully implemented using HTML parsing

Comment: How to do this in Telegram and wechat ?